Nuget 6 Central Project Management in a shared .NET Standard project, error when other projects in solution not CPM'd
I have two solutions, with one shared core project. I upgrade one solution's projects to use CPM (Central Project Management), but when I go back to the second solution, when I compile, I get an error

missing version in referenced package

At the moment one project in a solution being CPM'd is an issue, especially on .NET 6, with a .NET Standard 2.0 project, and even more so when the core project is also shared with older .NET 4.8 projects.
